# Can't connect to docker redis container from the host using StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, .net, docker, redis, .net-core

Not sure if it's the issue with connection string or my docker image. Running `docker container ls` I see

```
57cb0c982c76 redis "docker-entrypoint.s…" 0.0.0.0:32773->6379/tcp
```

The port seems to be mapped to the outside. I tried to run

```
docker run -d -P redis:alpine
```

with this and other different variations of parameters, and using StackExchange.Redis C# driver and it times out. Connection string looks like that:

```
localhost:6379,ssl=True,abortConnect=False
```

(no password). What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Tried with `docker run -d -p 6379:6379/tcp redis` (also redis:alpine). Still can't connect. `docker inspect` shows HostConfig:

```
        "PortBindings": {
            "6379/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "6379"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: i think the connection string needs to use the container's IP address rather than localhost (run `docker inspect <containerId>` to get that IP address)

Comment: @egnomerator In a wide variety of situations that IP address is not useful; I think on MacOS hosts it's unreachable even from the same host.  You never need it directly, and I'd discourage looking it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you ran `docker run -P` (with a capital `P`), Docker picks a host port for every exposed port in the container.  Which port exactly is in the `docker ps` output: `0.0.0.0:32773->6379/tcp` means Docker has picked port 32773, bound to all host interfaces, to forward to TCP port 6379.

This means your Redis client needs to connect to some IP address for the host, on the public-facing port 32773.  Changing `6379` to `32773` in your connection string should work.

It's more common to explicitly pick your own port; `docker run -p 6379:6379` (lowercase `p`) would use the "normal" Redis port 6379 on the host to forward to the Redis port in the container.  The one downside is that this can fail if anything else is already using that port (a host Redis daemon, some other container).

Comment: Tried it with redis:alpine and redis:latest. None worked. Still can't access it from the host... I'm a bit new to docker, what can I be doing wrong?